# Error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-4

I am getting following error with this linq query:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char] ToList[Char](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Char])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
var result =
(
    from citation in Db.Citation
    where citation.IsActive == true
    select new CitationViewModel
    {
        CitationID = citation.CitationID,
        CitationTitle = citation.CitationTitle,
        DocType = citation.DocType,
        DateOfPub = citation.DateOfPub,
        authors = citation.citation_Authors.Where(c => c.CitationID == citation.CitationID).SelectMany(b => b.Author.AuthorName).ToList(),
    }
);
```

and here is my view model:

```
public class CitationViewModel
{
    public int CitationID { get; set; }
    public string CitationTitle { get; set; }
    public IList<char> authors { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What  have you tried to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest modifying your code like this (note how the **authors** property is initialized now) :

```
var result =
(
    from citation in Db.Citation
    where citation.IsActive == true
    select new CitationViewModel
    {
        CitationID = citation.CitationID,
        CitationTitle = citation.CitationTitle,
        DocType = citation.DocType,
        DateOfPub = citation.DateOfPub,
        authors = new List<char>(citation.citation_Authors.Where(c => c.CitationID == citation.CitationID).SelectMany(b => b.Author.AuthorName)),
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem if you change the `IList<char> authors` property in `CitationViewModel` to

```
public IEnumerable<string> authors { get; set; }
```

and then remove the `ToList()` call in your projection. `SelectMany(b => b.Author.AuthorName)` returns an `IEnumerable<string>`.